# Custom Serialization/Deserialization in RestSharp 108

Tags: c#, restsharp

In updating from RestSharp 106 to 108 I've been unable to come up with an elegant replacement for the following. I've looked at the [migration documentation](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107) to no avail. There is a good chance I've missed something obvious.

Existing code that works in v106, which covered both XML and JSON

**Class A**

```
using RestSharp.Deserializers;


[DeserializeAs(Name = "response")]
public class ACertainResponse
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    //Etc
}

//JSON Payload {"response" : {"SomeProp" : "Some Value"}}
```

**Class B**

```
using RestSharp.Serializers;

[SerializeAs(Name = "request")]
public class SomeRequest
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    //Etc
}

//Resulting in : 
//{"request" : { "SomeProp" : "A Value" } }
```

I've found  `[JsonPropertyName("customName")]`, however, as the name suggests that is for properties only.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `SerializeAs` and `DeserializeAs` do when applied to a class because I can't seem to find documentation on them, but just using `JsonPropertyName` (or `JsonProperty` for Json.NET) is usually sufficient. What is the result supposed to look like when you serialize `SomeRequest` and what does the JSON that's being deserialized to `ACertainResponse` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I was unable to find a one size fits all solution as previouslt provided I was able to get it working by setting attributes for XML or JSON serialization explicitly. These attributes cover bother serialization and deserialization:

**JSON**

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonSerializable(typeof(LeadspediaRequest), TypeInfoPropertyName = "response")]
public class ACertainResponse
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    //Etc
}
```

**XML**

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
[XmlType("response")]
public class SomeRequest
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    //Etc
}
```